# excel formula, write based on another cell value

Tags: excel

I have a formula in Excel,
if the gran total of the cell:F50 is more than 70 then i want to write on the cell the label: "Bollo"
this formula does not work:**=IF(F50>70, "Bollo","")**
and i don't understand why
here the image of error[image]

Comment: Check your delimiter, it might be `;`

Comment: That is the correct syntax. I tested it on my excel and it's working fine.. try to check if you are using apostrophe or double quotes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Excel is supposing, use `;`

```
=IF(F50>10;"Bollo";"")
```